object sometimes resets too early in unity
so I am using IEnumerator reset and StartCoroutine(reset()) to reset the object to it's original position 3 seconds after the player releases the mouse button but sometimes, specially when I don't hold down the object for long it resets the object too early. are there any alternatives that I could use to do the same thing?
void Start()
    {
        attempts = Convert.ToInt32(text_attempts.text);
        attemptslimit= Convert.ToInt32(text_attempts.text);
        startposition = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
        pnl_resualt.SetActive(false);
        time_text.text = Convert.ToInt32(time).ToString();
        checker = false;
    }

    // This function is called when you left click the mouse.
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
        source.PlayOneShot(begin);
    }


    // This function is called when you leftclick with the mouse, hold and move it.
    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 mouseposition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (mouseposition.x < startposition.x)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(mouseposition.x, mouseposition.y, transform.position.z);
            checker = true;
        }

    }

    // This function is called when you release the mouse key. 
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (checker == true)
        {
            Vector2 currentposition = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position;
            Vector2 direction = startposition - currentposition;
            direction.Normalize();
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * force);
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
            attempts--;
            
            text_attempts.text = attempts.ToString();
            checker = false;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (score < Convert.ToInt32(objective.text))
        {
            time = Time.deltaTime + time;
            time_text.text = Convert.ToInt32(time).ToString();
        }
                 
    }

    // This function is called when a collision between the bird and the enemy occurres
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ENEMY")
        {
            collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            score++;            
            score_text.text = score.ToString();
            _particle.Play();
            source.PlayOneShot(hit);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(objective.text) <= score)
            {
                btn_win.SetActive(true);
                source.PlayOneShot(win);
                pnl_resualt.SetActive(true);
                resualt.text = "You Win!";
                
            }

        }

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Y" )
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            source.PlayOneShot(yhit);
            if (score < Convert.ToInt32(objective.text))

                {

                btn_lose.SetActive(true);
                source.PlayOneShot(lose);
                pnl_resualt.SetActive(true);
                resualt.text = "You lose!";

                }

        }

        StartCoroutine(reset());

    }
    
    // This function is called after the previous function
    IEnumerator reset()
    {
        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = startposition;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        if (attempts == 0 && score < Convert.ToInt32(objective.text))
        {
            btn_lose.SetActive(true);
            source.PlayOneShot(lose);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            pnl_resualt.SetActive(true);
            resualt.text = "You lose!";
        }
    }
}



There is no connection between OnMouseUp() and reset(). Are you sure that OnCollisionEnter() is called when you release your mouse button? 2. I'm a firm advocat against using coroutines for anything related to timing. This won't fix your issue, but will probably make it easier to handle timing in the future. 3. Use CompareTag()


@MaxPlay I'm curious - for your second point, you offer no alternatives to coroutines for timing issues. How else other than coroutines do you propose to wait for specific times without freezing the main thread?

@AustinDuling you'd make a classic countdown timer, I wrote about it in this answer regarding cooldowns. My main points are: 1. Coroutines are not precise, you say "wait X seconds" and then it always waits a little longer because it essentially just checks internally if "the time has passed". 2. Coroutines cannot be stopped while waiting, nor paused or sped up. Even if it is not needed in the final product, it could help during debugging. Regarding freezing the main thread: How and why would you do that? With Thread.Sleep, I presume?

@MaxPlay thanks for the response, the answer you've linked contained the information I was curious about. Also, maybe my question wasn't clear enough, but I was asking for other ways to pause/count time in a way which didn't pause the main thread because that's specifically what I didn't want to have happen, which is the reason I've used coroutines in the past. Thanks for an interesting post though, I'll keep that in mind moving forward
